# UTF-16LE Encoding with BOM

Tags: php, export-to-csv, utf-16le

I am working on a project that uses various special characters, I am working specifically on Arabic characters at the moment and I am struggling to get them to appear correctly in Excel when exporting from PHP, using my code as-is they appear as square brackets in the exported file.

I have tried a number of different methods to achieve this, some with better results than others, but ultimately every attempt has some form of issue.

I have done some research and found that encoding as UTF-16LE with BOM is the most likely way to get this to work, but so far I am unable to work-out how best to implement this.

---

### What I've tried

You will be able to see in my code below that I have several routes the code can take depending on four variables I set at the start of my code, I started putting these toggles in so that I can try different methods without making my code too unreadable.

At the moment, with the settings as they are in my code I am able to export the CSV but the Arabic characters display as square boxes - when I view the CSV in VS Code I can see that it has been unable to recognise an encoding type and will default to UTF-8, it will also tell me that it has successfully exported with BOM.

Switching to UTF-16LE seems straight-forward, and I had actually succeeded, but since getting it to export as BOM I've been unable to work-out how to get it back to UTF-16LE. Ultimately I think I've been staring at the code for too long and I suspect the fix will be quite quick but I'm just not able to see it at the moment, I was hoping that by explaining my issue in a question on SO that I'd be able to figure out what the issue is, but so far nothing.

I have tried to export as comma-delimited, tab-delimited, using `array_walk`, `iconv` and `mb_convert_encode` to convert the values to UTF-16LE, I have tried setting the Content-Encoding and Content-Type in the headers, using `\xEF\xBB\xBF` and `chr(255) . chr(254)` at the beginning of the export to convert to BOM (the current version below appears to be working best).

You'll also be able to see in my code that I've used both `fwrite` and `fputcsv` to see which one works best, `fputcsv` seems to be working best at the moment.

Any pointers would be appreciated - any clarification needed please ask away in the comments.

---

### My code so far

```
function convertToUTF16LE(&$value, $key) {
    $value = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $value);
}

$fput = true;
$iconv = true;
$UTF16 = true;
$walk = false;

if($UTF16 == true) {
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-16LE');
    header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-16LE');
} else {
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
}

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

$filesize = 0;
$delimiter = '\t';
$prefix = '';

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$headings = array("IATA Code", "Country", "Country Code", "English Name", "Current Name", "Is Primary?", "New Name");
if($UTF16 == true && $walk == true) array_walk($headings, 'convertToUTF16LE');

if($UTF16 == true) $prefix = "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // chr(255) . chr(254);
$filesize += fwrite($output, $prefix . 'sep=' . $delimiter . PHP_EOL);

if($fput == true) {

    $filesize += fputcsv($output, $headings, $delimiter, '"', "\0");

} else {

    $headings_data = implode($delimiter, $headings);
    $filesize += fwrite($output, $headings_data . PHP_EOL);

}

// This variable exists but the data has not been included in this code.
foreach($data_to_export as $row) {
    foreach($row as $k => $v) {
        if($UTF16 == true) $row[$k] = ($iconv == true ? iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $v) : mb_convert_encoding($v, 'UTF-16LE', 'auto'));
    }

    if($UTF16 == true && $walk == true) array_walk($row, 'convertToUTF16LE');

    if($fput == true) {

        $filesize += fputcsv($output, array(
            $row['code'],
            $row['country'],
            $row['countrycode'],
            $row['english_name'],
            $row['name'],
            ($row['isprimary'] ? 'Y' : 'N'),
            ''
        ), $delimiter, '"', '\0');

    } else {

        $row_data = implode($delimiter, $row);
        $filesize += fwrite($output, $row_data . PHP_EOL);

    }

}

header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);
exit(0);
```

Comment: Is the resulting file valid UTF-16…? What *exactly* is the issue you're struggling with? As a general advice I'd say: Excel notoriously sucks with encodings and the only truly safe way is to generate XLSX files instead of CSV files.

Comment: As VS-code doesn't recognise the encoding type and defaults to UTF-8 I don't think it is coming out as valid UTF-16. The main issue is that characters appear in the CSV as square brackets (occasionally using different routes in my code by adjusting the variables they come out as Chinese symbols). I would use XLSV but this is an import/export system that is setup to read CSV's, I'm not sure how much leeway I have in terms of adjusting that import script to work with XLSV.

Comment: To test what encoding a file is, open it using a text editor and specify that the editor shall open it as UTF-16LE. If the characters come out looking good then, then it's fine. For even more rigorous testing, open it in a hex editor and check the bytes by hand against the confirmed correct encoding for the characters you expect.

Comment: As for leeway… well, what's the purpose of this export? If it's defined that it must export CSV, probably also its expected encoding is defined? Then you shouldn't need to worry about Excel compatibility in particular. If you do want to provide a file which is guaranteed to work well in Excel, then you can hardly avoid providing an XLSX file specifically.

Comment: Importing CSV into Excel with the right encoding is a nightmare.
May you consider creating real excel files with phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ?